# HtmlHelper class and build errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Like most people, I have a lot of HtmlHelper classes in my asp.net mvc project.
When I add an extra parameter to a Helper method, I don't get any build error.
Which is logical, because it is used in the aspx page.
Is there any tool/option/... which shows you all the places where an error will occur at runtime?
I know you can use find all, but that's not very helpful in some circumstances.

thanks,

Filip

Comment: with Resharper it is possible, but with a "clean install" of visual studio...

Answer (score 0):

You can build MVC views.  Edit your MVC project file:

```
<MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>
```